# MySql query with "not in" not on unique column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like this in a MySQL DB:

```
Table readings:
reading_id, building_id, sub_id, reading_date

Table billings:
billing_id, building_id, sub_id, date_start, date_end
```

That's how it works:
foreach couple building_id, sub_id on the readings table I have several reading dates.

Some of this reading dates can be used as date_start or date_end in the billings table. What i want to achieve is a single query that returns me the couple building_id sub_id from the readings table where the reading_date is never been used nor as date_start nor as date_end for the couple building_id/sub_id.

Since building table is big (>5k rows) and i have to check all the buildings at the same time, i'd like the fastest way of doing this instead of making 5k queries.

I've tried this query but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.reading_id, a.sub_id 
FROM readings AS a
    LEFT JOIN billings AS b ON b.building_id=a.building_id 
                            AND b.sub_id=a.sub_id
WHERE reading_date NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT date_start 
                            FROM billings 
                            WHERE b.building_id=a.building_id 
                              AND b.sub_id=a.sub_id
                           )
AND reading_date NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT date_end 
                         FROM billings 
                         WHERE b.building_id=a.building_id 
                           AND b.sub_id=a.sub_id
                        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.  `NOT EXISTS` is usually faster than `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT r.reading_id, r.sub_id
FROM readings r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM billings b
                  WHERE b.building_id = r.building_id AND
                        b.sub_id = r.sub_id AND
                        b.date_start = r.reading_date
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM billings b
                  WHERE b.building_id = r.building_id AND
                        b.sub_id = r.sub_id AND
                        b.date_end = r.reading_date
                 );
```

For performance, you want two indexes:  `billings(building_id, sub_id, date_start)` and `billings(building_id, sub_id, date_end)`.

Notes:

- The `JOIN` in the outer query is unnecessary.  The `NOT IN` does the work you want.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is unnecessary when using `IN` (although this code was replaced by `EXISTS`).
- `SELECT DISTINCT` incurs unnecessary overhead in the outer query.